# Sound doesn't work through TV connected via HDMI

Tags: drivers, sound, hdmi

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and I've never used Linux before.

The TV is plugged into the back of my computer via one cable. Also when using windows 7 before the audio worked I had to download some HDMI audio package for my graphics card which is : amd radeon hd 6900 series 
However, there isn't any sound coming out. I presume I need some sort of driver or application. Could any kind soul point me in the right direction on getting this to work? I have a clean installation with no prior drivers or anything.

Comment: You need to click the audio indicator > Sound settings and explicitly select the HDMI output.

Comment: I can't seem to see my HDMI output listed do I need a driver or something before it can be recognized? Here is what it looks like for me https://gyazo.com/652db3834593c1252aea60978aa56466

Comment: You need to have the HDMI connected otherwise it won't be listed.

Comment: it is connected from the back of my TV via HDMI port to the back of my computer into the graphics card.

Comment: Bad news: There no alternative (proprietary) driver for AMD cards and 16.04 (or 14.04.5). If it doesn't work with the default driver there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Or press the "windows key" on your keyboard, type `sound` and there should be only one button popping up.

Click that, then select the output device.

I find it useful to right click the button on the launcher, and lock it, as I change output and input (mic) devices often.

Comment: I can't see the HDMI output do I need some sort of driver before it recognizes the output here is what it looks like for me https://gyazo.com/652db3834593c1252aea60978aa56466